# How to optimise final main.css using vite

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

I have a 20 vue components. Each of them contains a non scoped style blocks with lang=sass. Also I have some sass files like mixins.sass, variables.sass, functions.sass, etc. So when I build the app, whole sass compiled to single main.css file. In this case I have a problems:

1. File main.css contains a 20 duplicates of data from themes.sass and mixins.sass.
2. File too large and slow loaded.
3. Vite errors: `This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.` in reset.sass, keyframes.sass, variables.sass, classes.sass, functions.sass
   How to remove duplicates and decompose main.css to several files?

```js
//vite.config.js
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
            @import "${stylesDir}/themes"\n
            @import "${stylesDir}/mixins"\n
          `,
          quietDeps: true
        },
    },
  },
  build: {
    watch: {},
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
      }
    }
  },
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" lang="sass" href="@/sass/reset.sass" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" lang="sass" href="@/sass/keyframes.sass" />
  </head>
```

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "3.2.39",
    "vue-router": "4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite-plugin-simple-gql": "0.5.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "3.1.0",
    "sass": "1.54.9",
    "vite": "3.1.0"
  }
```

```js
//main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import router from '@/router'

import '@/sass/variables.sass'
import '@/sass/classes.sass'
import '@/sass/functions.sass'

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .mount('body')
```

Comment: Normally, your final `main.css` won't contain duplicated content. You should double-check to see if the duplicated style comes from multiple files or a single file. If it comes from multiple files, it is normal behavior. If it comes from `main.css` only, you might have a wrong config or wrong import somewhere. The way to debug is to remove each import one by one then build your project again to see which import caused the duplicate

Comment: As you have lots of files, and we don't know a lot about the contents of them, we could not give you an exact solution. But generally if each of your components have their own styles, why you use **non scoped style**? using **scoped style** may reduce probable conflicts. Also if you are using **dart sass**, maybe using [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) is a better option than **import**. Finally about the ```error```: This selector ..., maybe finding the lines of codes and posting them to the question could help you get better answer.

Comment: @hamid-davodi. of course I tried enabling scoped in the components. In this case main.css became to 2.5mb vs 500kb without scope.

Comment: @McLotos I said that I could not give you an exact solution, they were things that usually work fine. Also I could not see where you imported or used your **main.scss** or **main.css** in the question!

Answer (score -2):

Don't use SASS. You can directly write CSS and save it as a separate file.